# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not method. - Seleniun

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use selenium and when I use the webdriver Service to install a necessary component it gives this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/lucas/Desenvolvimento/Projetos/WebScraping/CAUC/CapturarCAUC_teste2.py",
> line 7, in 
> navegador = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py",
> line 172, in **init**
> self.service.start()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
> line 71, in start
> self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 966, in **init**
> self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1717, in _execute_child
> and os.path.dirname(executable)   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/posixpath.py", line 152, in dirname
> p = os.fspath(p) TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not method

The python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

service = Service(GeckoDriverManager().install) 

navegador = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: I'm not familiar to `Service` but according to exception you need to pass path to file while you pass `install` method

Comment: well, i deserve a spanking for being so inattentive. Missing() after install...

Here's the tip for those who have the same question and the link to the example of the documentation: [webdriver_manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)